# No media player working  except VLC by an ordinary user 

Tags: 12.04, banshee, rhythmbox, clementine, amarok

I am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on my machine.
Now a days as anormal user whenever I try to play any media player on my system except VLC, the system simply hangs for about 10-15 minutes and throws an error in terminal.
For **Rhythmbox**:
`avinash@titanic:~$ rhythmbox

Bus error (core dumped)`

For [**Banshee**](http://pastebin.com/KJS19LgW)

For [**Amarok**](http://pastebin.com/PiXEvjbb)

For [**Clementine**](http://pastebin.com/6kKLR0jV)

For super user all the above media players do work. But what for ordinary user ?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that when you launch these programs (apart from vlc) as normal user, you cannot access your audio hardware (hence the bus errors and permission denied). As you don't want to run these media players as root all the time, one quick fix that sometimes works is to add your user to the `audio` group (normally you don't have to do this in Ubuntu) with `sudo adduser <your username> audio`. This will add your *existing* user to the *existing* group. I had to do the same with VirtualBox, i.e. add myself to the `vboxusers` group to let it access my USB hardware.

Note: you must logout and then login again for the group changes to take effect for your user.